# Is there an easy way of creating a dynamic grid system for images of random sizes?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

Here is an example from Pexels.com:

[image: Picture from Pexels]

As you can see there are various image sizes and they all fit perfectly in together. The project I am currently working on has 100 pictures each of them has a random size and I'd ideally like to show them like this.

Is there a simple way of doing this? I'm using `Angular Material` as my grid system and just plain CSS, and AngularJS.

Any help would be incredible! Thank you.

Comment: Do the images have the same height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of open source Angular directives out there. I googled

> masonary view angular js

and found this [AngularJS Masonary Directive](https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry)

The concept you are describing is known as `Masonary Layout`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! Thank you.